# Hande Series of Web Requests in a specific way

Tags: web-services, web, fastcgi

I am sorry in advance; I am just learning Web development and my knowledge of it is quite limited.

I will describe my problem first.

I have relatively *large amount of data* (1.8-2 GB), which should be hidden from a public web access. However, a user should  be able to request via url call a specific small subset of *data* and see it on his / her webpage.

Ideally, I would like to write a program on a web server. Let's call it `./oracle`, which stores *the large amount of data* in *primary memory*.

Each web user should be able to make a specific string calls to `oracle` and see `oracle's`response on a web page as html elements.

There should only one instance of `oracle`, and web users should make asynchronous calls to it.

Can I accomplish the above task with `FastCGI` or any other protocols?
If yes could you please explain which tools / protocols should I use / learn?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up an Apache server because it's very common and you'll be able to find a lot of answers to any specific questions here on StackOverflow already.

You could also look into things like http://Swagger.io which can help you generate your API.

Unfortunately, everything past this really depends on what you use to set up your server. Big picture though:

1. You'll need to open up a port to listen to incoming requests
2. You'll need to have requests include the parameters they want to send to `oracle`

   - You could accomplish this the URI, like `localhost/oracle-request?PARAMETER="foo"`
   - You could alternatively use JSON in the body of the http request
   - Again, this largely depends on how you set up step 1
3. You'll need to route those requests to the `oracle`

   - This implementation depends entirely on step 1
4. You'll need to capture the output from the `oracle` and return it to the user

Once you decide on how you want to set up your server, feel free to edit your question and we may be able to provide more specific help.